# $\sin^{ \varepsilon }(x)\ln(x)$ Riemann integrable in ]0,1[?

Tags: calculus, integration

True or false?

If the function $f$ is defined as follows: $\sin^{ \varepsilon }(x)\ln(x)$ with $\varepsilon>0$. Is $f$ Riemann integrable in the interval $]0,1[$ ? 
I know piecewise continuity is a sufficient condition and I think $f$ is continuous on the open interval between 0 and 1. The only point where there would be a "problem" is $x=0$ because $\ln(0)$ is undefined, but this point is outside the interval. Could it be that easy? I think there must be something more that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varepsilon\gt0$, then since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\log(x)=0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\sin^\varepsilon(x)\log(x)
&=\lim_{x\to0}\color{#C00000}{\frac{\sin^\varepsilon(x)}{x^\varepsilon}}x^\varepsilon\log(x)\\
&=\color{#C00000}{1^\varepsilon}\lim_{x\to0}\color{#00A000}{(x^\varepsilon\log(\varepsilon x)-x^\varepsilon\log(\varepsilon))}\\
&=1\color{#00A000}{(0-0)}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\sin^\varepsilon(x)\log(x)$ is bounded on $(0,1)$.

Comment: So the answer is yes, because the function is bounded in 0 and in 1? Thank you !

Comment: @tim_a: That's right. You're welcome.